# $\sqrt{-1-i}$ in exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers

$$   \sqrt{ -1-i  \phantom{\tiny{!}}}   =   \sqrt{ 2  \phantom{\tiny{!}}}   { e  }^{ i \frac{  \pi    }{ 4  }    }
$$

Is that true? I have an exercice where it's asked to: calculate the squares root of $-1-i$ in trigonometric form. So I try and found that. But the correction gave is: $\sqrt{-1-i}=\sqrt{2}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{4}}$. And that's all, no more write in that correction.

What I did is:

step 1: $z^2=-1-i$;

step 2: $z=\left| z \right|e^{i\theta}$;

step 3: $\left| z \right|=\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$;

step 4: $\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{-1}\right)=\tan^{-1}(-1)=45°=\frac{\pi}{4}$;

step 5: I finally write the answer as $\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$.

So you say it's wrong? Where I failed? I learned that when it's $\sqrt[n]{z}$ there will be $n$ solutions. So here $\sqrt 2$ solutions but in the answer they just give the exponential like I wrote it.

Comment: Each non-zero complex number has two distinct square roots.

Comment: Do you know what $\sqrt{z}$ means for a complex number $z$? Can you check if that is true by definition? Some authors define it as the "principal square root" some treat it as a multi-valued function.

Comment: Note there are two values of $\sqrt{-1-i}$.  But no, you made some errors.  Figure out what $-1-i$ is as $r e^{(\theta +2k\pi)i}$ and $(-1-i)^{\frac 12}$ will be $\sqrt r e^{(\frac \theta 2)i}$ and $\sqrt re^{(\frac \theta 2 + \pi)i}$

Comment: Hmm.... actually... no.   $1+i$ is actually equal to $\sqrt 2 e^{\frac \pi 4 i}$.  So get $-1-i$ but manipulation $\frac \pi 4$ to make it express the negative value (do you know how to do that.  Then to get $(-1-i)^{\frac 12}$ take the square root of $\sqrt 2$ and divide the angles in such a way to get the two square roots (they are negatives of each other; do you know how to do that?)

Comment: @Aureole Note that your formula for the phase of $z$ is correct only if $\Re z>0$ which is not the case here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part

Answer (score -1):

Note that for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi],$

$$(r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))^{1/2}=(re^{i\theta })^{1/2}=\pm\sqrt re^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}=\pm\sqrt r (\cos \frac{\theta}{2}+i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}),$$

and yours is the case where $r=\sqrt 2,\quad \theta=-3\pi/4.$

Of course, if your square root only meant principal root, only the "$+$" root is your answer.

Comment: How do you find that argument ? I found 45° so Pi/4.

Comment: @Aureole Just visualize the angle (measured counterclockwise from the positive x axis) of the vector $(-1,-1)$ in the complex plane. It is $5\pi/4$, which of course corresponds with a reference angle of $\pi/4$.

Comment: yosh I'm a bit sleppy actually... So yeah effectively : $\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{5\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4}[2\pi]$

Comment: @Aureole No, get some sleep. Using $\theta=\pi/4$ in the above would be incorrect

Comment: @Aureole Technically for $+$ to correspond with principal root, the argument of the complex number should be in $(-\pi,\pi]$ so I updated it to $-3\pi/4.$